# Issues with Windows Form Label Text

Tags: c#, winforms

I've found that when I set the text of a label to one of the following two scenarios, that there is an issue in the formatting. I can't seem to find anyone else with this issue online, so I wanted to check in here.

Scenario one: "words (words)"
Gets changed to: "(words (words"

Scenario two: "75 words"
Gets changed to: "words 75"

This happens no matter what I type, if you have letters followed by letters inside of parenthesis, or if you have numbers followed by text.

"(words words)" works.
"words 75 words" works.

Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have [`RightToLeft`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.righttoleft%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property set to `YES` for your Label. Just do:

```
label1.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.No;
```

See: [RightToLeft property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.righttoleft%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The RightToLeft property is an ambient property. An ambient property
> is a control property that, if not set, is retrieved from the parent
> control. For example, a Button will have the same BackColor as its
> parent Form by default. For more information about ambient properties,
> see the AmbientProperties class or the Control class overview.
>
> The RightToLeft property is used for international applications where the
> language is written from right to left, such as Hebrew or Arabic. When
> this property is set to RightToLeft.Yes, control elements that include
> text are displayed from right to left.

Comment: Perfect! I haven't heard of that property before. Thank you.